# Printing PHP array values in one single string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array which I load as follows:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) 
{
  $pid = $item['itemId'];
  $q = $item['qty']; 
  $orderedItems[]=array('itemId'=>$pid,'qty'=>$q);
}
```

I now need to create a variable that will store the results of my array in a string just like this:

```
"For itemA ==> 2 sample
For itemB ==> 1 sample"
```

Comment: So basically `$itemString .= sprintf('For %s ==> %d', $pid, $q);` in your loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = join("\n", array_map(function($x) {return "For $x[itemId] ==> $x[qty] sample";}, $orderedItems));
```

Comment: Nice oneliner :-) Good idea!

Comment: Looks great but, how is my array referenced here? I only see the field names not the array name. What if I had another array with the same field names?

Comment: Oops, I left that out. It's the second argument to `array_map()`. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "";
foreach ($orderedItems as $item)
    $string .= "For item{$item['itemId']} ==> {$item['qty']} sample\n";
$string = rtrim($string);
```

Comment: You're missing the newlines between items (I know, they weren't in the original question because he didn't mark it up correctly).

Comment: @Barmar changed. (yes, it was because of the not working markup)